# get values from json data jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json, loops

This is soo easy and i got it working 2 days ago but now i cant find out how to get some values. I think my main problem is that i dont know when to use [] or not when loopin an array.

I hope someone can point me out what my problem is;

jquery post script;

```
var mydata = JSON.stringify(desktopicons);

            $.post(themeUrl + '/modules/module-save-desktop.php', { 
                data: desktopicons
            }).error(function() {
                $('#desktop').append('<div id="jsoninfo">Failed to save desktop.</div>');
            }).complete( function() {
                $('#desktop').append('<div id="jsoninfo">Desktop for ' + username + ' saved succesfully.</div>');
            });
```

json file;

```
[{\"myicons\":[{\"icon\":[{\"rel\":\"#\",\"id\":\"icon1\",\"class\":\"bookmark desktop-icon ui-draggable\",\"title\":\"bookmark\"}]},{\"icon\":[{\"rel\":\"#1\",\"id\":\"icon2\",\"class\":\"bookmark desktop-icon ui-draggable\",\"title\":\"bookmark1\"}]}]}]
```

jQuery get json;

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: userDesktopJson,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#desktop').append('<div id="jsoninfo">Data loaded.</div>');
                var myicons = jsondata['myicons'];
                $.each(myicons, function() {
                    alert('found!');
                });


            },  
            error: function() {
                $('#desktop').append('<div id="jsoninfo">Failed to load desktop.</div>');
            }   
        });
```

Its loading the file but i cant seem to get the values out of it.

EDIT

Ok so now i cant get the ID or title or whatever from the icons inside the each function,, i dont get it

```
$.each(myicons, function() {
                var iconid = this.id;
                var rel = this.rel;
                var title = this.title;
                var iconclass = this.class;

                $('<div />', {
                    'id': iconid,
                }).addClass(iconclass).attr('rel', rel).appendTo('#desktop'); 
                $('<div />', {
                    class: 'icon-title desktop-icon-title'
                }).text(title).appendTo(iconid);
            });
```

Comment: remove `'\'` from the json ,also check your console

Comment: which ones do i remove?

Comment: its like this now but still now working.. [{"myicons":[{"icon":[{"rel":"#","id":"icon1","class":"bookmark desktop-icon ui-draggable","title":"bookmark"}]},{"icon":[{"rel":"#","id":"icon2","class":"bookmark desktop-icon ui-draggable","title":"bookmark"}]}]}]

Comment: remove `var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);` because you are already added `dataType:'json'` no need to parse it again

Comment: i got this working but i still cant get a value out of it var myicons = jsondata['myicons'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);` , because  you already set `dataType:'json'`.
Then change `var myicons = jsondata['myicons'];` to `var myicons = data[0].myicons[0];`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: userDesktopJson,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#desktop').append('<div id="jsoninfo">Data loaded.</div>');
        var myicons = data[0].myicons[0];
        $.each(myicons, function() {
            alert('found!');
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#desktop').append('<div id="jsoninfo">Failed to load desktop.</div>');
    }
});
```

Also remove `\` from json data

```
 [{"myicons":[{"icon":[{"rel":"#","id":"icon1","class":"bookmark desktop-icon ui-draggable","title":"bookmark"}]},{"icon":[{"rel":"#","id":"icon2","class":"bo‌​okmark desktop-icon ui-draggable","title":"bookmark"}]}]}]
```

If you want to get each id from it try,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: userDesktopJson,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#desktop').append('<div id="jsoninfo">Data loaded.</div>');
        var myicons = data[0].myicons;
        $.each(myicons, function() {
            console.log(this.icon[0].id);
    });
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#desktop').append('<div id="jsoninfo">Failed to load desktop.</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I cant seem to understand when to use these brackets and when not ://

Comment: how would i get the id for each icon?>>var iconid = $(this).id; this is not working inside the each function

Answer (score 0):

your getting an array as a result so you should change it to this:

```
var myicons = jsondata[0]['myicons'];
```

Comment: var myicons = jsondata['myicons']; this seems to be working (cuz the rest of the jsscript keeps functioning after exetuting this code. its stops when i add the [0] to it. do i need to parse again for it to work ?